# Erro ao tentar adicionar uma coluna autoincrementável a um datagridview

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview, ado.net, dataset

Estou tentando adicionar uma coluna *autoincrementável* num `datagridview` mas não estou conseguindo descobrir o que falta para funcionar corretamente. O meu programa lê os dados de uma tabela do banco de dados e exibe em um `datagridview`. Preciso adicionar uma coluna *autoincrementável* chamada 'Legenda', pois os valores da tabela também são representados em um gráfico e a coluna 'Legenda' existe para facilitar a interpretação dos dados pelo usuário.

Segue parte do código responsável por isso. A coluna chamada 'Legenda' aparece no `datagridview`, mas as linhas ficam em branco.

```
Conexao ca = new Conexao();
string sql = "";
sql += " Select ";
sql += " CausaDef, Incidencia ";
sql += " From ";
sql += " Relat ";

ca.Conectar();
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, ca.cx);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "DetGraf");

object sumObject;
sumObject = ds.Tables["DetGraf"].Compute("Sum(Incidencia)", "");

ds.Tables["DetGraf"].Rows.Add("TOTAL", sumObject.ToString());

DataColumn Legenda = new DataColumn();
Legenda.ColumnName = "Legenda";
Legenda.DataType = typeof(int);
Legenda.AutoIncrement = true;
Legenda.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
Legenda.AutoIncrementStep = 1;

ds.Tables["DetGraf"].Columns.Add(Legenda);

dgvDetGraf.DataSource = ds.Tables["DetGraf"];

ca.Desconectar();
```

Comment: Coloque o total separado do Grid Principal e você não pode misturar Legenda com os dados que vem da base. o que você quer mostrar coloque uma figura do que deseja implementar, eu já vi dois erros no seu código só não vou postar uma resposta porque eu fiquei com mais duvida kkk  !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui achar uma solução da seguinte forma:

```
ds.Tables["DetGraf"].Columns.Add(Legenda);

int index = 0;
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["DetGraf"].Rows)
row.SetField(Legenda, ++index);

dgvDetGraf.DataSource = ds.Tables["DetGraf"];
```

Abs!

Answer (score 0):

Tenta modificar o código, em vez de criar essa coluna "auto-increment", tenta trazer o número da linha do banco de dados, através da função ROW_NUMBER isso se se for SQL SERVER. Então só aplique a fonte de dados na datagrid.

```
Conexao ca = new Conexao();
string sql = "";
sql += " Select ";
sql += " ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CausaDef) AS Legenda,";
sql += " CausaDef, Incidencia ";
sql += " From ";
sql += " Relat ";

ca.Conectar();
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, ca.cx);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "DetGraf");

object sumObject;
sumObject = ds.Tables["DetGraf"].Compute("Sum(Incidencia)", "");

ds.Tables["DetGraf"].Rows.Add("TOTAL", sumObject.ToString());

dgvDetGraf.DataSource = ds.Tables["DetGraf"];

ca.Desconectar();
```

Comment: Olá, Murilo! Obrigado pela resposta. Infelizmente meu banco de dados é Access.

Comment: sua tabela não tem uma chave primária do tipo auto-incremento que serviria  como a coluna "legenda"?

Comment: Sim, tem uma chave primária. O problema é que a tabela é apagada e preenchida várias vezes. A chave já está na faixa de mais de 2000... rs
Acredito que esta chave não possa ser zerada :(